# can having a suspected heart attack and awaiting an ambulance at work be included as absence?

Tags: human-resources, united-kingdom, work-time, health, sickness

I am facing redundancy and work is including the time from when I collapsed, was administered 1st Aid and awaiting the ambulance as absence.  I start work at 8.30am and the incident happened at 11.30am.  the ambulance left the grounds at 12.50pm and I work until 3pm.  However, work are including this as half a day's absence. Can they include the time an employee is on the premises?  What about duty of care?

Comment: It's most appropriate that you submit your question to HR and if you company does not have an HR, to the firm's office manager. We are not privy to your company's internal policies regarding the management of absences or time off, and I am voting  to close your question on that basis - FYI, it takes 5 votes to close the question.

Comment: To be fair, this isn't a policy question. OP, you should speak to ACAS for clarity over the legality, however my (genuine) question is what difference does this make? Does it increase your risk or reduce your settlement?

Comment: what's the Q here are they targeting you for redundancy for poor time keeping and using this incident as an example? redundancy is not normally calculated based on time served down to a the half day normally full years or months are what is counted. And what does duty of care mean in this instance?

Comment: @Dan, it's debatable whether it's a policy question or not, but as you point out it's definitely a legal question, which is also considered off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

I would *strongly* recommend talking to your Union Rep or an employment lawyer.

If you are off sick, the company has to pay you [Statutory Sick Pay](https://www.gov.uk/statutory-sick-pay/overview).

I would think that they only need to pay you for the time that you were working.  I agree that it sounds harsh that they won't pay you for the time you were incapacitated - but you really need to talk to a qualified employment professional.